# Error Parsing tmx and JSON file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, tiled

I'm trying to load a simple map made by Tiled inside my Android studio project.
I'm using libGDX to made a simple platform game.
In Tiled I've just imported a tileset, created a platform and anything else.

Now I would like to understand in the witch part that I am failing my upload because I am not able to understand why I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: mapassets.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.getDependencyFileHandles(TmxMapLoader.java:116)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:74)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:59)
at com.arcadan.push_the_player.TiledTest.create(TiledTest.java:28)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:150)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)


Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing XML on line 1 near: 
{ "columns":10,
 "image":"..\/..
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:330)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:61)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
... 6 more
```

Here the map .tmx :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.4" tiledversion="1.4.3" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="20" height="20" tilewidth="12" tileheight="12" infinite="0" nextlayerid="2" nextobjectid="1">
 <editorsettings>
  <export target="../../android/assets/MyMap.tmx" format="tmx"/>
 </editorsettings>
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="../mapassets.json"/>
 <layer id="1" name="Tile Layer 1" width="20" height="20">
  <data encoding="csv">
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,11,12,13,14,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,21,22,23,24,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,31,32,33,34,35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,41,42,43,44,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Here is my frustrating mapassets.json(this file is inside assets/mapAssets folder in my project):

```
{ "columns":10,
 "image":"..\/..\/assets\/mapAssets\/mapassets.png",
 "imageheight":128,
 "imagewidth":128,
 "margin":0,
 "name":"mapassets",
 "spacing":0,
 "tilecount":100,
 "tiledversion":"1.4.3",
 "tileheight":12,
 "tilewidth":12,
 "type":"tileset",
 "version":1.4
}
```

and here how I load .tmx file:

```
    @Override
public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,w,h);
    camera.update();
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("MyMap.tmx");
    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you've saved your tileset as a `.json` file but the **libGDX** implementation in `TmxMapLoader` assumes it's in **XML**.

You can see that in the [source code for `TmxMapLoader`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/2bd6b742560f03bddfad390d077ac02c21a0e4bc/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TmxMapLoader.java#L116).

Save your tileset as a `.tsx` file instead and reference that from your `.tmx` file and it should work.